# Can't get the Excel VBA to copy PPT files

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I have the following code, I attempted to modify it so it loops through a list in excel, opens each ppt file in the list and copies that to a new ppt file.  But it is getting hung up and has an error during the loop.

```
Sub tmp()
'Set a VBE reference to Microsoft PowerPoint Object Library
   On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    Dim PPApp As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim i, j As Integer
    Dim pres1, new_pres As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Dim oslide, s, oSld As PowerPoint.Slide
    Dim oShape, oSh, oshp As PowerPoint.Shape

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim list As Worksheet

    Set PPApp = CreateObject("Powerpoint.Application")
    PPApp.Visible = True
    Set new_pres = PPApp.Presentations.Add
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set list = wb.Worksheets("Powerpoint File List")
    LastRow = list.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    new_pres.PageSetup.SlideSize = ppSlideSizeOnScreen


                 ' this is not working
       For i = 1 To 1 ' LastRow
            filepath = list.Range("A" & i).Value
            Set pres1 = PPApp.Presentations.Open(filepath)
            For j = 1 To pres1.Slides.Count
                pres1.Slides.shapes(j).Copy
                 new_pres.Slides.Paste
                new_pres.Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "PasteSourceFormatting")

            Next j
             pres1.Close
             Set pres1 = Nothing
        Next I

NormalExit:
 Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
 Call MsgBox("Error:" & vbCrLf & Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description, _
 vbOKOnly, "Error inserting files")
 Resume NormalExit

End Sub
```

Comment: Please include what the error is and on which line it occurs.

Comment: If I change the j loop to the following:                                              pres1.Slides(j).Copy
                 new_pres.Slides.Paste
                new_pres.Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "PasteSourceFormatting")                              then it copies the 1st page in the powerpoint the number of times the powerpoint being copied has pages.

Comment: what does "copies that " mean? For a single file what do you expect to see happen?

Comment: if you are copying the files why are you opening them? Batch file copy them and Shell execute?

Comment: that is beyond my skill level at this point,  do you have an example?  I am self taught and have just been doing this for 2 months.

Comment: As @QHarr mentions, it isn't necessary to open these files. You can copy any file on your drive to any other location using a [`filesystemobject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa265015(v=vs.60).aspx). You can easily find tutorials and sample code on how to use it. Also your variables are not being declared the way you (probably) think they are. If you separate variables with a comma, they all do not get assigned the same data type. You must put `Dim i As Integer, j As Integer` or else `i` will be a variant.

Comment: I don't want to move these.  I have about 30 powerpoint presentations that need to be merged.  each powerpoint presentation is likely to have different formatting.   Each has to maintain its original formatting.   I want to copy each presentation into a masterfile in order.  I have changed the code and now it takes the first slide in each presentation and copies it each time, instead of each slide.

Comment: Also I got it to work in powerpoint, but I am trying to make it more univerals (there are multiple weekly presentations that pull in from multiple sources).  Thus I am trying to do this in excel.  When I move the code to excel I am having issues.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work,  it was the PasteSourceFormatting that I needed when running from powerpoint that wasn't needed when converting to excel.  This pulls every file from the list, opens, copies to a master powerpoint with formatting intact, and closes.  in the end I have a new master powerpoint that has all of the presentations that are on the list

```
Sub tmp()
'Set a VBE reference to Microsoft PowerPoint Object Library
Application.CutCopyMode = False
   On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Dim PPApp As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim pres1 As PowerPoint.Presentation, new_pres As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Dim oslide As PowerPoint.Slide, s As PowerPoint.Slide, oSld As PowerPoint.Slide
    Dim oShape As PowerPoint.Shape, oSh As PowerPoint.Shape, oshp As PowerPoint.Shape
    Dim PPShape As Object


    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim list As Worksheet

    Set PPApp = CreateObject("Powerpoint.Application")
    PPApp.Visible = True
    Set new_pres = PPApp.Presentations.Add
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set list = wb.Worksheets("Powerpoint File List")
    LastRow = list.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    new_pres.PageSetup.SlideSize = ppSlideSizeOnScreen


                 ' this is not working

         k = 1
        For i = 1 To LastRow
            filepath = list.Range("A" & i).Value
            Set pres1 = PPApp.Presentations.Open(filepath)

            For j = 1 To pres1.Slides.Count
                  pres1.Slides(j).Copy


                 new_pres.Slides.Paste
               ' new_pres.Slides.Paste

               ' new_pres.Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PasteSourceFormatting")
               k = k + 1
            Next j

            pres1.Close


            Set pres1 = Nothing

        Next i

        For Each oSld In new_pres.Slides
            oSld.HeadersFooters.Clear
            oSld.HeadersFooters.SlideNumber.Visible = msoFalse
            oSld.HeadersFooters.DateAndTime.Visible = msoFalse
        Next oSld

        With new_pres.SlideMaster.Shapes
            Set oshp = .AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 700, 520, 100, 50)
            oshp.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Name = "Arial"
            oshp.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 7
            oshp.TextFrame.TextRange.InsertSlideNumber
        End With
        'ActivePresentation.PageSetup.FirstSlideNumber = 0
        new_pres.Slides(1).DisplayMasterShapes = msoTrue

        Set oshp = Nothing

        response = MsgBox(prompt:="Is this For Official Use Only?", Buttons:=vbYesNo)
        If response = vbYes Then
            txt = "For Official Use Only"
             ' If statement to check if the yes button was selected.
        Else
         ' The no button was selected.
            MsgBox "Then it is assumed this is a Boeing Proprietary presentation"
            txt = "Boeing Proprietary"
        End If
        With new_pres.SlideMaster.Shapes
            Set oshp = .AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 300, 520, 100, 50)
            oshp.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Name = "Arial"
            oshp.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 7
            oshp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = txt
        End With

        injdate = InputBox("Please enter the date for the Stand Up")

        With new_pres.SlideMaster.Shapes
            Set oshp = .AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 10, 520, 100, 50)
            oshp.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Name = "Arial"
            oshp.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 7
            oshp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = injdate
        End With






    Application.CutCopyMode = True
NormalExit:
 Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
 Call MsgBox("Error:" & vbCrLf & Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description, _
 vbOKOnly, "Error inserting files")
 Resume NormalExit

End Sub
```